# Transfer SQL Azure servers, Storage Accounts away from CSP subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We have a CSP subscription through a partner, and the whole experience is rubbish.  Costing / billing APIs not available, can't use our Office 365 Azure AD, can't use SendGrid, can't see the cost of resources in the portal, loads of features missing.  It's rubbish.

We're moving away and want to transfer a substantial number of SQL Azure servers (with many pools and databases) and Storage Accounts (with lots of items) to another, new PAYG subscription, which uses our O365 Azure AD.

@AzureSupport on Twitter pointed me to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

But this says, "The source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant."

It suggests two ways forward:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

**But...** The "Change Directory" option is not present for CSP accounts (lo and behold! another missing feature)

2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer

**But..** Heading to https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions as instructed gives me a 500 error, with "We are sorry, but we could not complete that operation.".

**Also..** Of course, the CSP (Ingram) do not offer any of these kinds of options on their sub management portal.

@AzureSupport then recommended I post here.

Can anyone advise / help please? Would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently blocked, as there is not a good workflow to migrate from CSP to Pay-as-you-go, as the below User Voice entry suggests others are looking for the same. Please up vote and comment on this.

[Change subscription from CSP to pay-as-you-go](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/17827438-change-subscription-from-csp-to-pay-as-you-go)

As for getting switched back to PAYG, I suggest exporting your data and importing in to new services that have been set-up under your desired account set-up. If you need the instance names, these will need to be deleted before the data can be imported into the newly created service with the existing instance names, in cases where instances names can be reused after deletion of the particular service.

There is currently no supported means to migrate a subscription away from CSP once migrated, from my investigation.

[Use Azure Data Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-overview) to migrate from source to target. This though, will not allow you to keep the same instance names, as both the source and target will need to exist at the same time.